# getting array of objects(nested) from api, looping 3x times , opinion, reactjs

Tags: reactjs, loops, object, nested

I fetch data from api in parent which is array of objects . To get data 
  that i need to render in child, I have to map 3 times like the example 
  shows under.

My questions are:

> 1)      Is there a better way(or better practice) to loop in such dept?
>
> 2)      How to limit to only 10 results inside the 3rd loop
>
> 3) How to store those needed values from loops to state that I can reuse 
>           them in child?

```
const matchInfo = this.state.matchData.map((data, i) =>
                      data.tournaments.map((tour, j) =>
                        tour.matches.map((matc, k) =>
                        //For example the data I am looking for inside the loops 
                          <div>
                             <div>{tour.name}</div>
                             <div>{data.name}</div>
                             <div>{matc.something.home.name}</div>
                             <div>{matc.something.away.name}</div>
                                           . ...//and so one
                           </div>
                        )
                      )
```

Any help would be appreciated

[image]

Comment: can you provide what kind of data you are getting in response exactly?

Comment: "data": [ { "realcategories": [
                        {
                            "tournaments": [
                                {                             
                                    "matches": [
                                        {
                                            "_dt": { },
                                          
                                            "teams": {
                                                "home": { }
                                                "away": { }     }

Answer (score 1):

> 1.)      Is there a better way(or better practice) to loop in such dept?

No, this looks fine.

> 2.)      How to limit to only 10 results inside the 3rd loop

```
tour.matches.slice(0, 10).map(...)
```

> 3.)      How to store those needed values from loops to state that I can reuse 
>           them in child?

Can you please elaborate, what you want to store in state and in which child you want to reuse them?

**Edit:**

> 3.)      How to store those needed values from loops to state that I can reuse 
>           them in child?

If you want to create a child component and use the data in it, just create a new component and pass the data as props:

```
const Card = ({ data, tour, match }) => (
  <div>
    <div>{tour.name}</div>
    <div>{data.name}</div>
    <div>{match.something.home.name}</div>
    <div>{match.something.away.name}</div>
    // and so on...
  </div>
);
```

And then in your parent component:

```
const matchInfo = this.state.matchData.map((data, i) =>
                    data.tournaments.map((tour, j) =>
                      tour.matches.slice(0, 10).map((match, k) =>
                        <Card data={data} tour={tour} match={match} />
                      )));
```

Comment: In parent <Parent /> I fetch data from API and limit data results by 10(data from loops - than I want to update state with loops values), in child <Child /> I want to render  data got from loops over props.state- from parent)  in a card fashion.

Comment: Does each <Child /> represent a card? Do you want the child component as a replacement for your div's in your code snippet?

Comment: Yes this is exactlly what I need

Comment: Thank you very much for taking time and solving this, everything works fine, just slice function doesnt work, it is showing all the cards, maybe because it's mapped so many times, thoughts on that?

Comment: Hmm that's weird, are you sure you're slicing the array that you want to slice? You can find more about the slice function here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Comment: Yes it's weird, I'm slicing in the last loop(....match.slice(0,10).map()..........), but it is not working. Can you think of any other way how to get 10 cards at the end, br

Comment: For this I think I need a bit more code. If you slice first and then map, you should definitely get 10 cards (or less if your array is smaller than 10). Could you post all code from your parent component?

Comment: this.state = {
      matchData: [],
    };}
  async componentDidMount() {
    try {
      const result = await axios.get(API);
      this.setState({
        matchData: result.data.doc[0].data[this.props.sportId].realcategories,
        isLoading: false
      });}}
  render() {
    const MatchData = this.state.matchData.map((data, i) =>
      data.tournaments.map((tour, j) =>
        tour.matches
           .slice(0,10).map((match, k) => (
            <Card key={i + j + k} data={data} tour={tour} match={match} />
          ))));
    return <Slider}>{MatchData}</Slider>;
  }
}

Comment: Sorry for the structure of code, I left out constructor, export of Parent component, but main logic is there, I hope it will help, I had to cut code because of the length of comment

Comment: I addeda picture from react dev tools

Comment: Well I expected you to edit your question, not my answer and post your code in there as well to keep it readable ^^ Anyway, the problem is, that you're having multiple items in your categories (matchData) array and multiple tours per category. Let's say you have 5 categories and 7 tours per category, you will get at most 5 * 7 * 10  = 350 items instead of 10. Now the question is obviously which data you want to show. Do you just want to show 10 random matches? Do you want to show one match per tournament? Do you want to show the next 10 matches by date?

Comment: Sorry Damian I am new with Stack. Ok to explain it to you. When I loop 3 times like you helped me I get as many cards as there are hits, like shown on picture. I want to show 10 random cards from MatchData, this is my query, not by date not random.